# Including libc directory for multiple platforms/versions

Tags: c, linux, unix

These directories on my platform (Ubuntu) is required to be passed to clang so it can parse code that includes libc headers properly:

`/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`

`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include`

`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed`

What is the simplest way to find the location of this directory on other platforms and versions of gnu libc? I need this to make a portable build script.

Please tell me this is standardized in some way or form. Pkg-config?

Comment: Clang *should* be built to look in the correct locations for system header files; if it's not, that seems to be a problem with the way it was configured.

Comment: @ephemient: Well where does whatever that builds clang gets that information then?

Comment: It's hard-coded into the Clang source, and modified to suit the distribution.  I'll answer with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`llvm/tools/clang/lib/Driver/ToolChains.cpp`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/ToolChains_8cpp_source.html) searches for GCC installations, with various hard-coded paths for different platforms.

On Gentoo, Debian, and Ubuntu, the distribution-provided `clang` source patches this file to look in distribution-specific locations (e.g. [gentoo/sys-devel/clang/files/clang-3.1-gentoo-runtime-gcc-detection-v3.patch](http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/sys-devel/clang/files/clang-3.1-gentoo-runtime-gcc-detection-v3.patch?revision=1.1&view=markup), [debian/clang_3.1-8/debian/patches/21-searchPathHeaders.diff](http://patch-tracker.debian.org/package/clang/3.1-8), etc.).